# How do I avoid reusing ids in Vue.js framework templates and components to have valid HTML5 syntax?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, dropdown

I am writing a web page code with vue.js components. In the below I posted my template part of one of my vue components that I called it "dropCompo.vue". this component simply add a dropdown to every part of web page that I use it. I don't have any problem with my page and it is rendered correctly on browsers. I also added bootstrap3.4.1 framework and use classes of it. for example "dropdown-menu" class for making dropdowns.

My question is that in such cases that bootstrap (or my own code) uses ids for some part of its code and these ids are necessary for dropdown to work, when the page is rendered in browser and I inspect it, I see that I have multiple tags(according to the number that I used the components in several parts) that have the same id. but we know that using multiple tags with the same ids is not valid in HTML5 syntax and we should avoid it.

How can I avoid it, where the purpose of using components in Vue is to build something and use it multiple time? is it something that Vue did not consider?

this is the "template" part code: "I used persian language for my web"

```html
<template>
  <div id="serv2" class="dropdown">
    <span class="padd dropdown-toggle" id="services2" data-toggle="dropdown">
      موضوعات کتب
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="services2" id="drop-serv2">
      <router-link
        v-for="item in mohtava"
        :key="item.title"
        :to="item.linkItem"
      >
        {{ item.title }}
        <i v-bind:class="item.icon"></i>
      </router-link>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this is the image of code in the browser inspect part:
[image: two id image]

Comment: Refactor your code to not rely on `id`. What boostrap code/css requires `id`?

Comment: because it defines toggling of dropdowns according to "id" that we set for the tag that have ' data-toggle="dropdown" ' attribute.

Comment: According to this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns-example an ID is not required for a dropdown. There's some "aria" properties that are accessiblity features. Anyhow you should be able to freely modify anything in vue like `<span :id="'myid-'+5">` in where `5` can be an incrementing variable.

Comment: dose it mean that I must use dynamic "ids" every where in my code? even I have some static code that I don't need to change my Ids? and it means that I must add some javascript codes in data and methods and props and so... on every component?

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?